# Check empty field value in view result counter

Tags: 7, views

I am using view result counter to combine and display multiple fields.
I want to check the empty condition for field.
How to check this in rewrite result option in view result counter field.

FYI,I am combining city ,state,country fields in view result counter.

Please help me if anyone knows the answer